# How to add CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS to file.cmake?

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, ubuntu-16.04

I want to add some flags to the c and c++ compiler in the following file.
How should I do this so as not to encounter an error?

FLAGS = -O3 -g -fno-reorder-blocks-and-partition -Wl,--emit-relocs

Please also mention the flags that need to be removed for these flags to work.

[file cmake in github](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/HHVM-3.30/CMake/HPHPCompiler.cmake)

please guide me.

thanks.

this file is HPHPCompiler.cmake from HHVM project.

Comment: Best to check first, if the build type `RelWithDebInfo` already provides you with `-O3` and `-g` You adding debug info to ALL configurations would definetly be unexpected behaviour.

Comment: thanks @fabian  . Please explain more if possible, I have very little knowledge about this.
On the other hand, the -fno-reorder-blocks-and-partition -Wl, --emit-relocs flags are more important to me.
Because I want the relocation mode of functions and blocks to be activated so that I can use optimizations such as BOLT.

Comment: If you're asking about what I mean with "configuration": For single configuration generators such as `Unix Makefiles` you can specify [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) as cache variable during configuration. As for adding other flags: The `add_compile_options` and `add_link_options` may work for you, with generator expressions for limiting the flags to some configurations. (I won't reaearch the the meaning/valid combinations of those flags and which compilers they are applicable to.)